# Javascript Regex Positive Lookahead

Tags: javascript, regex, debugging, syntax

What is the correct syntax for defining the beginning and end of a a regex `word` as the boundary in a capture group as follows:

```
var $classes = $( 'body' ).attr('class'); // string 'foo bar sub-theme-home';
var regex = /sub-theme-(?=(\b))/;
var sub_theme = regex.exec($classes);
console.log(sub_theme[0]);
```

This is matching `sub-theme-` and while it's fine if I need to include that in  my capture and do string replacement to remove it, I'm having trouble figuring out the proper syntax for my `(?-(\b))/` capture group.  Seems like with positive lookahead, `sub-theme-` should be the omitted portion and `home` should be captured... help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just capture the string you're looking for?

```
var $classes = $( 'body' ).attr('class'); // string 'foo bar sub-theme-home';
var regex = /sub-theme-(\w+)/;
var sub_theme = regex.exec($classes);
console.log(sub_theme[1]);
```

See more about parenthesized substrings and the result of `regex.exec(...)` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Description).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var regex = /sub-theme-(\w+)/;
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript RegExp don't support some of the advanced regular-expression features like lookbehindes,named capturing groups....
the book(Professional Javascript for Web Developers,3rd edition)p136:

Pattern Limitations

> Although ECMAScript’s regular-expression support is fully developed,
>   it does lack some of the advanced regular-expression features
>   available in languages such as Perl. The following features are not
>   supported in ECMAScript regular expressions (for more information, see
>   www.regularexpressions. info):

- The \A and \Z anchors (matching the start or end of a string,
  respectively)
- Lookbehinds
- Union and intersection classes
- Atomic grouping
- Unicode support (except for matching a single character at a time)
- Named capturing groups
- The s (single-line) and x (free-spacing) matching modes
- Conditionals
- Regular-expression comments

Despite these limitations, ECMAScript’s regular-expression support is powerful enough for doing
most pattern-matching tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive response, I was aware of most of these limitations, though probably not the specifics of all of them.  However, you're right that it's good to document for anyone else who reads this question.